# Alternative to wxStaticText in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, static-text

I have a problem in which I update StaticText fairly often(once every second) and every time it updates, it tears the frame.  This is very bothersome on Windows but on Linux it never happened. I tried doing TextCtrl Readonly but I get ugly boxes around text I was wondering if there was a better option for updating text in wxPython frequently that wouldn't tear the screen. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try using the Freeze() / Thaw() methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I understood better what you meant by "tearing" the frame - I don't seem to have problems with changing StaticText values after a window is created (though sometimes it's necessary to call `Layout` on a Panel or Dialog).

However, if you're really just looking for read-only TextCtrl's without the "ugly boxes" you should use `TextCtrl(style = wx.NO_BORDER | wx.TE_READONLY)`.  The combination will give you what you want - what appears to be a `StaticText`, but that can't be user-edited and doesn't display a border.  You'll also be able to select its value (which may or may not be an advantage).